# Удаление профиля

Tags: поддержка

Как удалить отсюда профиль? Нигде не нашел информации.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

Answer (score 3):

там кнопка удалить профиль
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/206320# номер ессно твой.
Или руками, профиль -> править -> удалить профиль

Comment: И этот ответ дал.... Удалённый пользователь :-D